# How not to change the text size for different screens in android

Tags: android, text, bluetooth

How do I make the text size not change for different screen densities? According to my requirement, I don't want to text to change the size. I am creating the text view from the text, to be displayed in BLE device not on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

mostly font size changes depending on device size only if you use `sp` so you need to define in `dp` instead of `sp`

```
android:textSize="20dp"
```

Comment: It will still change for different screen densities, right? I think sp is just scaled by the user's preferred text size

Comment: I tried setting something like this  but no luck  tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,size);